# Elasticsearch override field value in search results

Tags: elasticsearch

The use case is that, I want to hide product price(change to 0) if a user is not logged in.

```json
PUT /products
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "price": {
        "type": "scaled_float",
        "scaling_factor": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
POST /products/_doc
{
  "price": 101
}
```

```json
POST /products/_doc
{
  "price": 102
}
```

```json
POST /products/_doc
{
  "price": 103
}
```

I try to use `runtime_mapping` with the following script, but the result still has the original data.

```json
GET /products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "price": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": "if(0 == 1) {emit(333);} else{emit(222);}"
    }
  }
}
```

What do I miss? Is it the script condition invalid?

Thanks.

**-- Edit --**

**I expect all the price to be 222. But the original price is returned.**

Expected out put:

```js
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "XXphNoMBcFxgyV6Mwe1-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 222
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "XnphNoMBcFxgyV6Mye2c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 222
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "X3phNoMBcFxgyV6M0e2W",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 222
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "YHphNoMBcFxgyV6M3u0V",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 222
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Actual output:

```js
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "XXphNoMBcFxgyV6Mwe1-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 101
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "XnphNoMBcFxgyV6Mye2c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 102
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "X3phNoMBcFxgyV6M0e2W",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 105
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_id" : "YHphNoMBcFxgyV6M3u0V",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: "but the result still has the original data" - do you mean that the result has `_source` field with the original data and you want it to be removed? Can you add sample response from your search?

Comment: @qaziqarta Hi, thanks for comment, I have updated the question. Would you mind to take another look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retry on the example in the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-override-values.html), I realized that I missed out the `fields` key in query body.

```js
GET /products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "price": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": "if(0 == 1) {emit(333);} else{emit(222);}"
    }
  },
  "fields": ["price"]
}
```

Now I get both the original and script fields.